# Send Invites on Menu Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I want to be able to review Form submissions before sending out Calendar invites to add to students Google Calendar.

The sheet I am organizing the invites in (pulling in eventID and one row per session) is separate from the Google Form Submission tab.

ColA: Name
ColB: Email
ColC: Session Title
ColD: eventID (populated through VLOOKUP function

Here's the code I have so far:

```
function addAttendeeToEvent() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Invites');
  const [h, ...vs] = ss.getDataRange().getValues();//assume one header row  
  let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('bd8tmudge9f6ti9vgtm7kkagss@group.calendar.google.com');
  if (cal) {
    vs.forEach((r, i) => {
      let ev = cal.getEventById(r[4]);
      if (ev) {
        ev.addGuest(r[1]);
      }
    })
  }
  let attendeeEmail = [2]
  let calendarId = '2980k01ekkpeeb4e1qsb40hhgg@group.calendar.google.com'
  let eventId = [4]
 
}
```

TIA!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? For example, I cannot understand the relationship between `ColA: Name ColB: Email ColC: Session Title ColD: eventID (populated through VLOOKUP function` and your showing script.

Comment: ColB is the email that needs to be added to the event. ColD is the corresponding eventID that they need to be added to. 
When I ran the script, there were not errors, but it did not share the event.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your current issue and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and your reply, I understood your current situation is as follows.

- Columns "B" and "D" are the email addresses you want to add to the event and the event ID you want to use.

When I saw your script, the value of `vs` is the data except for 1st row. In this case, when `let ev = cal.getEventById(r[4]);` is run, the value is retrieved from the column "E" instead of column "D". By this, `if (ev) {}` is `false`. So, `ev.addGuest(r[1])` is not run. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue of `When I ran the script, there were not errors, but it did not share the event.`.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let ev = cal.getEventById(r[4]);
```

#### To:

```
let ev = cal.getEventById(r[3]);
```

- By this modification, the event ID retrieved from column "D" is used.